# GameCenter unique achievement ID

Tags: xcode, gamekit

I already have one Live game in AppStore. This game contain around 100 achievements and 10 leaderboards. So my XCode project tuned to use these specific ID's
My GameOne bundle id is: "**com.superpuper.GameOne**"

So now i want to create iPad version. iPad version uses the same achievements and leaderboards.I dont want to use universal iPad/iPhone binary, i want to compile exactly separate iPad binary. Because price will be different.
So for new iPad version i created new bundle id :
"**com.superpuper.GameOneHD**"

I opened GameCenter via itunesconnect and began to fill achievements and leaderboards.
In this case i dont want to change achievements or leaderboards ID's because
my "GameOne" and "GameOneHD" already configured for certain ID's, so i want open itunesconnect/gamecenter and copy all achievements and leaderboards from "**GameOne**" to "**GameOneHD**" , But i cant do that because and error :

"*The Achievement ID you entered has already been used. Enter a unique Achievement ID and try again*. [1]"

What should i do ? No way to fill same achievements with different ID's because this will cause a tonns of code-change

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this confirmed anywhere, but in my experience achievement and leaderboard IDs must be unique **across all of your apps**. If you have server-side code that manages achievement IDs, you'll need to tell your server which version of the app it's talking to.

To make it easy, just do something similar to your bundle ID: append a suffix to your IDs for your HD app. In my case, I prepend an underscore for the paid version of all my achievements.

Comment: but does it have to be unique across all apps in the world?

Comment: Just to be 100% sure I had a friend try to create an achievement on his account that I am using on mine and it worked. They are unique **across all of your apps** as Jeremy says, **not across all of Apple**